# Class extend from abstract class with same propriety name

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

so here's my class declaration

```
abstract class person {
    const NAME='person';
    public static function get_name(){
        return self::NAME;
    }
    abstract public function get_description();
}

class me extends person{
    const NAME = "me";

    public function get_description(){
        return "this describe " . self::NAME;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the const name is declared twice in both Classes person and me.
I declare it in class "person" because it's there where we use it in the implementation of the method get_name()
I declare it also in class "me" because I want the get the name of "me".

so when I make the call

```
echo me::get_name()
```

I want it to return "me"

Actually it returns "person" so what I'm missing here so it would return "me" instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your abstract method to:

```
abstract class person {
    public static function get_name(){
        return static::NAME;
    }
}
```

This will use late static binding in PHP as noted in the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php